# Create action with a non-persisted record with persisted associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a basic checkout page, and here's what I have so far:

The checkout is hosted off of `transactions#new`, and the form is built off of a new `Transaction` object. `Transaction` has a number of nested models underneath it:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :shipping_address, :products
  # ...
end
```

`User`, `Product`, and `Location` (Shipping Address) can be persisted when you arrive at the checkout page, depending on the user flow. `Product` is always persisted upon arriving at the checkout page.

This setup works for me so far except on the failure cases. I've been trying to re-create the new `Transaction` record (with the previously entered in user info) to display the appropriate error messages, and I had tried doing this in my controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
  end

  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new params[:transaction]

    # ...
  end
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TransactionsController#create
>   Couldn't find Product with ID=1 for Transaction with ID=
>
> ## Request Parameters
>
> {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"blahblahblah", 
>   "transaction"=>{"products_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1", 
>   "quantity"=>"1"}}}}

Does anyone know what's up with this? Let me know if you need anymore info about my setup here... tried to pare this issue down to the bare essentials...

---

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_transactions
  has_many :products, :through => :product_transactions
end
```

and

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_transactions
  has_many :transactions, :through => :product_transactions
end
```

and

```
class ProductTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Hey, could you post your relation between `Transaction` and `Product`?

Comment: @Azolo - Appended to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason you're getting that error is because you're supplying an `id` with `products_attributes`, since you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the `product` with that `id` HAS to already be in the association. This is because the `products_attributes=` method is expecting to either create or modify the records in the `products` association.

Since the `Product` is already persisted and you're just trying to create the `ProductTransaction` you would need change your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to include `:product_transactions` instead.

This part of your question threw me off

> `User`, `Product`, and `Location` (Shipping Address) can be persisted when you arrive at the checkout page, depending on the user flow. `Product` is always persisted upon arriving at the checkout page.

I don't know if you need to be able to define a product... **But** if you need to create a `Product` on the checkout page it would make more sense to define it in the context of a `ProductTransaction` *(ie. `ProductTransaction` accepts `product_attributes` or `product_id`)* instead of the context of a `Transaction`.